# Freeform inline errors not showing

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

We recently moved to another server and as a consequence of said move, it appears as if forms that displayed inline errors correctly on the old server (and still do), no longer do so on the new server. We have verified that the source code for the forms is identical.

EE 2.5.5
Freeform Pro 4.0.10

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
{exp:freeform:form
  form_name="demo"
  required="first_name|email"
  inline_errors="yes" 
  rules:email="valid_email" 
  return="/contact-us/thank-you" }

<div class="contact">
  <div class="form_row">
    <div class="half">
      <label for="c1">First Name *</label>
      {freeform:field:first_name attr:id="c1"}
      {if freeform:error:first_name}<span class="error">* {freeform:error:first_name}</span>{/if}  
    </div>
    <div class="half">
      <label for="c11">Last Name</label>
      {freeform:field:last_name attr:id="c11"}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_row">
    <div class="half">
      <label for="c2">School Name</label>
      {freeform:field:school_name attr:id="c2"}
    </div>
    <div class="half">
      <label for="c21">Position/Title</label>
      {freeform:field:position_title attr:id="c21"}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_row">
    <div class="half">
      <label for="c3">Phone</label>
      {freeform:field:phone attr:id="c3"}
    </div>
    <div class="half">
      <label for="c31">Email Address *</label>
      {freeform:field:email attr:id="c31"}
      {if freeform:error:email}<span class="error">* {freeform:error:email}</span>{/if}  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form_row">
    <div class="half">
      <label for="c4">City</label>
      {freeform:field:city attr:id="c1"}
    </div>
    <div class="half">
      <label for="c41">State</label>
      {freeform:field:state attr:id="c41"}
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form_row checkboxes">
    <span class="label">Language(s) of interest:</span>

    {freeform:field:languages_of_interest attr:class="contact_li"}

  </div>

  <div class="form_row">
    {freeform:field:user_message attr:class="swap" attr:value="(350 characters max)"}
  </div>

  {freeform:submit}

</div>

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Comment: Template code please :) Also, the latest version of Freeform, as of this writing, is **4.1.3**. Please upgrade to the latest version to see if that helps. Also check your .htaccess file, sometimes redirection (which inline errors use) doesn't occur as it should on a new server.

Comment: Are you also on Freeform 4.1.3 now? Given that the EE and Freeform setup are the same on both servers, this usually points as some server setting being different between the old and new server. I suggest having a look at the .htaccess files: it's one of the common causes for these server move issues.